# Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment when create @+id/map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

when my app try to get fragment show the follow logcat **Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment"**

**Here is my activity_maps.xml layout file:**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Here permission in my AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
 <application>
        <permission
              android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx..permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
              android:protectionLevel="signature" />

            <uses-permission android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>




            <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
            <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true" />
            <!-- End of copy. -->

    <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="APIKEY" />

        <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        </application>
```

**Finally my java code:**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
 public GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);



        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.maps, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));     
    }
}
```

**All code above load from a fragment inside the swiptab map is the second tab   :**

```
public static class Fragmento2 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NAMBER1 = "section_namber";

    public Fragmento2() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps,
                container, false);


        return rootView;
    }
     @Override

     public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

     }
}
```

while try to inflate the activity_maps on fragment2 show this logcat

```
08-26 21:21:15.597: I/Google Maps Android API(17325): Google Play services client version: 7571000
08-26 21:21:17.373: I/Google Maps Android API(17325): Google Play services package version: 7899436
```

and down:

```
**"Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment when create @+id/map"**
```

Answer (score 0):

In `activity_maps.xml` you have used SupportMapFragment by defining

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

So in your activity you can not use `MapFragment`.You have to import `SupportMapFragment` like

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

instead of

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
```

you can use `SupportMapFragment` like this.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

instead of

```
 MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using API >= 14, then use `getFragmentManager()`. If you want compatibility with devices below API 14 then you can use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Therefore, `getSupportFragmentManager()` is used to deliver newer features to older platforms.

If

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

does not work then try

```
GoogleMap googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: not getFragmentManager() , use getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: the wrong appers when inflate activity_maps from the fragment2 view onCreateView() event..

Comment: What is minSdkVersion of your app?